# PHP get data from text file (line and multispacing separated)

Tags: php, regex

I have to update data from text files exported from an application. It looks like this:

```
customer001         1000          10        10000
customer01         10000         100      1000000
customer1            100        1000       100000
customer0002        1000           1         1000
customer012         1000          10        10000
```

The problem is I cannot specify the number of space character to separate the data.

Comment: Is there a minimum number of space characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guneverdie, I use your data as string. However you can read your application export file using php file functions.

```
$data = "customer001         1000          10        10000
         customer01         10000         100      1000000
         customer1            100        1000       100000
         customer0002        1000           1         1000
         customer012         1000          10        10000";


$customers_all = explode( "\n", $data);
$customer_individual = array();

foreach ( $customers_all as $customer){

    $customer_with_spaces = explode( " ", $customer);
    array_push($customer_individual, array_filter($customer_with_spaces));        
}

print_r($customer_individual);
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have a file called test.txt, which contains your data:

you can use this simple awk command:

```
awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3" "$4}' test.txt
```

and put as many spaces you want. here I have put only one space.
In fact you can use any character here as a separator.

try this :

```
awk '{print $1","$2","$3","$4}' test.txt
```

this will add a comma between the values. See what works out for you.

Comment: I dont understand this code. It is PHP code, right?